# How to serialize a custom findBy() method?

Tags: symfony, serialization, doctrine, fosrestbundle

When I use `findBy()`, my data is automatically serialized.

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy($params, $orderBy, $limit, $offset);


/**
 * @VirtualProperty
 * @SerializedName("catagory")
 * @Groups({"user"})
 */
public function getCategoryId()
{
    return $this->category->getId();
}
```

But when I use a custom `MyfindBy()` from my repository, the data is not automatically serialized. How can I automatically serialize the data?

SOLUTION :

Don't use select at the querybuilder.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the documentation of symfony serializer from visiting this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

(follow your desired verson documentation from there)

After getting your objecs by custom query u can pass the whole object array named `$persons` to the  `$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($persons, 'json');`  and send it to your response . after installing serializer components to your project .

please inform me if it not works for you.Thank you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help but it doesn't work but i found the solution.
I remove from my querybuilder the select. As soon as you i select, it will return an array and not serialize.